Ubuntu Rsyslog cannot read certificates because permission denies
I am setting up a syslog serer that will listen for logs from a Fortigate firewall. Rsyslog gets error
'/home/syslog_cert/ACDC_CA.pem' could not be accessed: Permission denied"


This is my rsyslog config:
$ sudo cat /etc/rsyslog.conf

# /etc/rsyslog.conf configuration file for rsyslog
#
# For more information install rsyslog-doc and see
# /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/configuration/index.html
#
# Default logging rules can be found in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf

global(
  DefaultNetstreamDriver="gtls"
  DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile="/home/syslog_cert/ACDC_CA.pem"
  DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile="/home/syslog_cert/server-key-pem.pem"
  DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile="/home/syslog_cert/server-key-nopass.key"
)



#################
#### MODULES ####
#################
module(load="imtcp" StreamDriver.Name="gtls" StreamDriver.Mode="1" StreamDriver.Authmode="anon")
input(type="imtcp" port="6514")

module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
#module(load="immark") # provides --MARK-- message capability
# provides kernel logging support and enable non-kernel klog messages

module(load="imklog" permitnonkernelfacility="on")

###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################
# Filter duplicated messages
$RepeatedMsgReduction on

# Set the default permissions for all log files.
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

# Where to place spool and state files
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


Restart service:
sudo systemctl restart rsyslog
sudo systemctl status rsyslog 
sudo journalctl -u rsyslog


When I restart the service I get the following error:
systemd[1]: Starting rsyslog.service - System Logging Service...
rsyslogd[626]: rsyslogd: error: defaultnetstreamdrivercafile file '/home/syslog_cert/ACDC_CA.pem' could not be accessed: Permission denied [v8.212.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
rsyslogd[626]: rsyslogd: error: defaultnetstreamdriverkeyfile '/home/syslog_cert/server-key-nopass.key' could not be accessed: Permission denied [v8.212.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
rsyslogd[626]: rsyslogd: error: defaultnetstreamdrivercertfile '/home/syslog_cert/server-key-pem.pem' could not be accessed: Permission denied [v8.231.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
rsyslogd[626]: rsyslogd: could not load module 'lmnsd_gtls', errors: trying to load module /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so: /usr/lib/x6_64-linux-gnu/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory [v8.2312.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2066 ]
rsyslogd[626]: rsyslogd: tcpsrv could not create listener (inputname: 'imtcp') [v8.2312.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2066 ]
rsyslogd[626]: rsyslogd: activation of module imtcp failed [v8.2312.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2066 ]


Permissions:
$ ls -ld /home
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul 17 10:16 /home

$ ls -l /home
drwxr-x--- 3 mrx  mrx 4096 Jul 17 10:16 mrx 
drwxr-xr-x 2 syslog                syslog                4096 Jul 17 10:16 syslog_cert
drwxr-x--- 3 ubuntu                ubuntu                4096 Jul 11 08:16 ubuntu

$ ls -l syslog_cert/
-rw-r----- 1 syslog syslog 5442 Jul 17 10:02 ACDC_CA.pem
-rw-r----- 1 syslog syslog 1678 Jul 17 10:02 server-key-nopass.key
-rw-r----- 1 syslog syslog 1938 Jul 17 10:02 server-key-pem.pem




Your rsyslog service is running as a user ?

The user is syslog.
ps aux | grep rsyslogd
syslog      4345  0.3  1.5 248008 14848 ?        Ssl  15:37   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE

Try move the certs to /etc/rsyslog.d
It worked for me :)
Credit to rgerhards from this post:
https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/5272
